# empty related table throws error in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I have created a basic one-to-one relationship in Laravel to allow users to upload a logo to a profile. Logos are stored in their own table.

I also seeded the user profiles into my database, but I don't have any logos.

The problem that I am having is that I am receiving a "Trying to get property of non-object" error when I call their profile and no logo exists.  I am hoping to insert a stock logo that they can replace, but I am having no luck.

My code, inside of the show.blade.php file is:

```
<div class="thumbnail">

                @if ("{{ $contractor->logo->contractor_id }}" !== NULL)
                    <img src="../{{ $contractor->logo->name }}">
                @else 
                    <img src="../assets/images/logo.png">
                @endif
        </div>
```

For reference, here is my controller action:

```
public function logos($id)
    {

        $contractor = Contractor::find($id);
        return View::make('contractors.logos')
            ->with('contractor', $contractor);
    }

public function logo_upload($id){

  $input = Input::all();
  $rules = array(
      'file' => 'image|max:3000',
  );

  $validation = Validator::make($input, $rules);

  if ($validation->fails())
  {
    return Response::make($validation->errors->first(), 400);
  }
    $file = Input::file('file');
    $destinationPath = 'uploads/logos';
    $extension = $file->getClientOriginalExtension(); 
    $filename = str_random(12).".{$extension}";
    $upload_success = Input::file('file')->move($destinationPath, $filename);
    $path = Input::file('file')->getRealPath();

    if( $upload_success ) { 

        $logo = new Logo;
        $logo->name = $destinationPath ."/". $filename;
        $logo->contractor_id = (Input::get('contractor_id'));
        $logo->save();
       return Response::json('success', 200);
    } else {
       return Response::json('error', 400);
    }
}
```

Is there a better way to swap in a placeholder logo, when the related table has no foreign key present?  TIA

Comment: Try with `@if (isset($contractor->logo))`

Comment: how is the relationship defined? putting your model code will be helpful here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is one of the few spots I'd recommend the use of PHP's error suppression operator, `@`.

```
@if( @$contractor->logo->contractor_id )
  <img src="../{{ $contractor->logo->name }}">
@else 
  <img src="../assets/images/logo.png">
@endif
```

Another option is first checking for `$contractor->logo`:

```
@if( isset($contractor->logo) && $contractor->logo->contractor_id )
```

Side note: no need for `{{ }}` within an `@if` in Laravel.

Comment: Thank you, that works perfectly.  Good to know on the {{ }} too.